# after converting batch file to exe Windows Defender shows the file as trojan why?

Tags: windows, batch-file, antivirus, virus, trojan

i wrote a batch script to delete shortcut virus from a usb drive and to display the hidden folder and files.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE SHORTCUT VIRUS REMOVER
ECHO SHORTCUT VIRUS TEMPORARY REMOVER
ECHO THIS TOOL IS MADE BY BHARGAB(MAXYSPARK)
SET /P DRIVE=ENTER THE DRIVE LEETER 
CD /D %DRIVE%:
DEL *.LNK
ATTRIB -H -R -S /S /D /L %DRIVE%:\*.*
PAUSE
```

but after converting the batch(.bat) file to .exe file using **Bat To Exe Converter** the .exe file is detected as **Trojan** Virus
Why????
[image: Screenshot Of Windows defender]

I've allowed the file in Windows defender.

Comment: Files with *.bat* extension are considered as a threat in Windows. But I'm not sure after being converted to *.exe* file is still a threat. Btw, I think Windows Defender detect it as Trojan is because your script is related to hidden files and external drive like usb. (But detected as Trojan is still weird)

Comment: I suspect that Defender treats all "executables with batch file hidden inside" as potential Trojan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you haven't converted them to the correct architecture for your machine. I have had the same issue with the same antivirus and it was fixed by converting to x64 not x32 (default)

Comment: I have had the same issue and my domain name has been banned because of a link to a setup file containing an exe file generated with "bat to exe converter". 

If your need is to avoid the ms-dos black Window that shows up when starting a BAT file, you can use quiet.exe :   http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/

Comment: this is a correct answer. upvoted

Comment: no it is not. Defender stopped considering BAT packagers as malwares but SOPHOS and others still do. The problem is with the very concept of packaging a batch in an exe, which is considered dangerous in some environments. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: This is not a correct anwer. I am having the same issue. My system is Windows 64 and I have tried to compile a simple batch Test.exe in 32 bits (format invisible = 21 viruses), 32 bits (format visible = 21 viruses); 64 bits (format invisible = 14 viruses); 64 bits (format visible = 14 viruses) using VirusTotal and "Exe to Bat converter.exe". By the way, the exe converter had no viruses.